# How to make static libraries with Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, static-libraries

This is the Makefile

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -pedantic -Werror -g 
LDFLAGS=-lm
RM=rm -f
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.c)
TARGETS=$(SOURCES:.c=)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)

.PHONY: all clean

all: test_stack

%: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@  $< 

%.a: %.o
    ar rcs $@ $<
    ranlib $@

test_stack: genstacklib.a test_stack.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(TARGETS)
```

I have the files genstacklib.c, genstacklib.h and test_stack.c
Now I want to compile genstacklib as static library
When test_stack calls the methods of genstacklib, it throws an exeception:
for example: "undefined reference to `genStackNew'"
I don't get why test_stack can't access the methods, for my current understanding it should have access to the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please copy and paste the exact errors you get into your question, with proper formatting, and also including the compile or link command that make printed.  A statement like "throws an exception" is not precise and in fact is not really accurate because exceptions are thrown from running programs, but (if I understand your problem correctly) you are not able to link your program.

The problem is that the order of arguments to the linker is critical: all *libraries* must appear on the link line *after* all object files.  Also the order of libraries matters but since you have only one that's not an issue.

In your rule:

```
test_stack: genstacklib.a test_stack.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

The `$^` variable expands to the prerequisites, in this case `genstacklib.a test_stack.o`.  So on your link line the library will appear *before* the object file, which won't work.  Rewrite your rule like this:

```
test_stack: test_stack.o genstacklib.a
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

so the library comes after the object files and it will probably work.

As an aside, the variable `LDFLAGS` generally contains flags that manage the linker.  Library references like `-lm` are traditionally put into a variable `LDLIBS` instead.  Of course this is just convention but it's useful to follow conventions unless there's a good reason not to.